# Eclipse running a java application and a jar file

Tags: java

I am using Eclipse for running my applications.

=> All this time I have been running as a java application (using Run as Java application option) and it works.My program executes for 20 minutes and prints some data .

Now I tried to create a Runnable jar. I am able to get jar file and execute.But it exits after 1 minutes.There are no prints from SOP.I have kept one just immediately after main and that is also not getting printed. How to debug this?

I am getting this Error now:

```
JAR export finished with warnings. See details for additional information.
  Exported with compile warnings:input.java
  Jar export finished with problems. See details for additional information.
    Could not find main method from given launch configuration.
```

But there is a `public static void  main(String[] args)` in the input.java file. I am not sure why is it complaining when I try to run from command prompt and it gives
`no main manifest attribute`.I did not create any file with that name. What has gone wrong here ?

Comment: Not clear. Can you please Explain with some code snippet?

Comment: I have a program with 2 files. file1 and file2-has java main and calls file1. I was able to print data and all. but when I did jar file I am not able to print anything. infact there is no print line I have exactly after main ..so looks my main immedite line is not executed

Comment: How are you executing your .jar ?

Comment: what does your manifest look like?

Comment: I do not have manifest file. i am using Extract required binaries option. I had some warnings it says export with compile warning in details...not sure how to see the warnings

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are mentioning is because, the compiler can not find the main class within the jar. 
To solve this we use a MANIFEST file.

A MANIFEST  file is a special file that contains information about the files packaged in JAR

refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) for details on MANIFESTS

To solve your problem. we need to define a MANIFEST file and define the main Class inside it.

Create a `MANIFEST.MF`

file for your jar and specify the class that has the main method
using format

```
Main-Class: Mypackage.yourPackhage.OurClass
```

UPDATE

when you are creating the JAR, follow [Define Jar Manifest](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-35.htm)

to Include a Manifest file in your jar

UPDATE 2

Structure should be like

```
YourJAR
    META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
    CLASS1
    CLASS2
```

Comment: Thanks Mukul. what if I dont have ant package name? I have 2 files, 1 class is having main and another classs is used by main class. so how sould I have the contents. just main class is fine? and also the file structure where I should create?

Comment: I am seeing this Error: JAR export finished with warnings. See details for additional information.
  Exported with compile warnings: sample.java
  Jar export finished with problems. See details for additional information.
    Could not find main method from given launch configuration.

Comment: if you dont have any package name, then just put the class name. 
you should create MAINFIEST.MF file inside a META-INF folder

refer to update 2 for sample structure

Comment: @TheLearner by the way, can you update the post with command for how did you create your jar and how are you running it?

Answer (score 0):

A manifest is a one-line text file with a "Main-Class" directive.  You need to create this file (call it something useful like manifest.txt) in notepad or wherever.

In the file you want the line:
Main-Class: file2

make sure there's a hard return at the end of the line.

Then use jar like this:
`jar cvfm sample.jar manifest.txt *.class`